# REGEX: Delete the content of all files that do not contain the word/words

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

suppose I have several files, some of them have the exact words `MIRELA HOME` and some doesn't.

So, I want to delete the content of all files that do not contain the word/words, so that files to be empty, 0 bytes.

For example, I have a html file with this text, that doesn't have the exact words: `MIRELA HOME`

`Karon, magpadayon kami uban pa nga maayo ug magamit nga app gikan sa kalibutan sa Android nga magamit alang sa mga kompyuter nga adunay GNU / Linux, Windows ug..`

So, after using regex, all the sentences to be deleted, so to have an empty file.

My regex will find all files witch doesn't have the specified words, but I don't know how to make a replacement as to delete the entire file.

SEARCH: `(?s)\A(?!.*(MIRELA HOME).*$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\A(?:(?!\bMIRELA HOME\b).)*\z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- Filters: `Whatever you want`
- Directory: `Path\where\your\files\are`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A                  # beginning of file
        # Tempered Greedy Token
    (?:                 # non capture group
        (?!                 # negative lookahead
            \b                  # word boundary
            MIRELA HOME         # string to find
            \b                  # word boundary
        )                   # end lookahead
        .                   # any character
    )*                  # end group, mayy appear 0 or more times
\z                  # end of file
```

Comment: your regex makes the opposite, seems that is deleted the files that has the words  `MIRELA HOME` . But I need to delete all those files that DOESN'T contain `MIRELA HOME`

Comment: @JustMe: I've misread ;( See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)(MIRELA HOME)(?!\w)).*`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>